# How can I see what is happening under the covers when an Elasticsearch query is executed?

Tags: elasticsearch

For Elasticsearch 1.7.5 (or earlier), how can I see what steps Elasticsearch takes to handle my queries?

I attempted to turn debugging on by setting es.logger.level=DEBUG, but while that produced a fair amount of information at startup and shutdown, it doesn't produce anything when queries are executed.  Looking at the source code, apparently most of the debug logging for searches is just for exceptional situations.

I am trying to understand query performance.  We're seeing Elasticsearch do way more I/O than we expected, on a very simple term query on an unanalyzed field.

Comment: I'm having some success in instrumenting the 1.7.5 source code so that it does log more info at the debug level.  It just takes a while to follow the code down and get the instrumentation added along the way.  Of course, this won't be particularly maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

With ES 1.7.5 and earlier versions, you can use the [`?explain=true` URL parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) when sending your query and you'll get some more insights into how the score was computed.

Also starting with ES 2.2, there is a new [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html)  which you can use to get more insights into timing information while the different query components are being executed. Simply add `"profile": true` to the search body payload and you're good to go.

Comment: The profile API seems like it would be helpful here.  I wish I had time to update to 2.2 at the moment.

Comment: The explain parameter isn't very useful to me currently, as the queries I'm looking at right now are simple exact-match queries, where I don't care about the score.

Comment: Then, indeed, what you're looking for is the Profile API.